# Can Hortonworks Ambari manage multiple clusters

Tags: hadoop

I have been looking all over the web to see if Ambari can manage multiple clusters like Cloudera does. Is this possible in Ambari? If so, how? I have looked all over the Ambari web UI and only see options to add a new host or service, but nothing about adding a cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in [roadmap](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMBARI-1518). For now it's possible to do so in API level, from version 2.0 it would be possible to manage multiple clusters from web UI.